# How do I append to a Java exception?

Tags: java, exception, stack-trace

I am new to Java and exceptions in general.

In my prior C/Perl programming days, when I wrote a library function, errors were passed back by a boolean flag, plus some kind of string with a human-friendly (or programmer-friendly) error message.  Java and C++ have exceptions, which is handy because they include stack traces.

I often find when I catch an exception, I want to add my two cents, then pass it along.

How can this be done?  I don't want to throw away the whole stack trace... I don't know how deep the failure occurred and for what reason.

I have a little utility library to convert a stack track (from an Exception object) into a string.  I guess I could append this to my new exception message, but it seems like a hack.

Below is an example method. Advices?

```
    public void foo(String[] input_array) {
        for (int i = 0; i < input_array.length; ++i) {
            String input = input_array[i];
            try {
                bar(input);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                throw new Exception("Failed to process input [" 
                        + ((null == input) ? "null" : input)
                        + "] at index " + i + ": " + Arrays.toString(input_array) 
                        + "\n" + e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Peter: Thanks for the tip.  I'll do that.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Exceptions can be chained:

```
try {
    ...
} catch (Exception ex) {
    throw new Exception("Something bad happened", ex);
}
```

It makes original exception the *cause* of the new one. Cause of exception can be obtained using `getCause()`, and calling `printStackTrace()` on the new exception will print:

```
Something bad happened
... its stacktrace ...
Caused by:
... original exception, its stacktrace and causes ...
```

Comment: Is it a best practice to wrap extension such as IOException with a more general exception in this case Exception?

Answer (score 4):

Typically you throw a new exception which includes the *old* exception as a "cause". Most exception classes have a constructor which accept a "cause" exception. (You can get at this via `Throwable.getCause()`.)

Note that you should almost never be catching just `Exception` - generally you should be catching a more specific type of exception.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a different constructor:

```
Exception(String message, Throwable cause)
```

The message is your "two cent" and you include the catched exception, which will be shown in a stacktrace printout

Answer (score 0):

You can add the underlying cause to a newly created exception:

```
    throw new Exception("Failed to process input [" 
                + ((null == input) ? "null" : input)
                + "] at index " + i + ": " + Arrays.toString(input_array) 
                + "\n" + e.getMessage(), e);
```